# Why does a dot product equation have infinite (or many?) solutions?

Tags: vectors, inner-products

I am reading some books on geometric algebra (not the topic for the question), and one of them says that, if we want to solve for $\vec{x}$ given $\vec{a}$ and $\alpha$:
$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x}=\alpha$$
Let any $\vec{x}$ be a solution, then any vector of the form $(\vec{x}+\vec{b})$ ,  $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{b}=0$ is also a solution.

I have tried playing around with equations and vectors, but I don't seem to get why. I only come up with cases where it doesn't work. Or perhaps I do not understand the question at all.

Here's the full extract, as well as the same question but with the cross product:

[image: Screenshot of paragraph]

Thanks for any insights you may have and share.

Comment: What are the cases you’ve come up with where it doesn’t work? Do you know that $\vec a\cdot (\vec b+\vec c)=\vec a\cdot \vec b+\vec a\cdot \vec c?$

Comment: Yeah, but are we safe to assume that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 0$ ? If so, why is that?

Comment: If $\vec a=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ then $\vec b=(a_2,-a_1,0,\dots,0)$ is such a vector. If $a_1=a_2=0$ then any $(b_1,b_2,0,\dots,0)$ is such a vector. Similarly for $a_2,a_3.$ If they aren’t both zero, then $b=(0,a_3,-a_2,0,\dots,a_n).$

Comment: In $n$ dimensions the set of $b$ such that $\vec a\cdot \vec b=0$ is $n-1$-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of application of the linearity property of the inner product. Precisely, one has
\begin{align*}
\langle a, x + b\rangle = \langle a,x\rangle + \langle a,b\rangle = \langle a,x\rangle = \alpha
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: But are we safe to assume that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 0$ ? If so, why is that?

Comment: I think the proposed relation is miswritten. If $x$ is a solution, then $x + b$ is also a solution when $\langle a,b\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I just found the errata and it says that. I can't believe I have been thinking about it for the past 3 hours. Thanks for the suggestion, it turned out to be the case!!

Comment: I am glad to help!